# Trying to add the current page url as &Source= to the new document link

Tags: url, url-rewriting, new-document

With multiple list views on same page, I am trying to add the current page url as &Source= to the new document link.  So just looking to pull the current page URL and add it as the &Source to the +new document link.  Not sure if I have to encode it or not?

Comment: Ok, got this to work as far as changing the new document link but just need to somehow add the current page url as the variable "&source" at very end of the new url:    
function changeLink() {
      $("#idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ6").removeAttr('onclick');
      $("#idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ6").attr("href", "#");
      $("#idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ6").click(function () {
        NewItem2(event, "https:….//_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=%7b2D0B41F6-84B5-469D-86DC-446215EA47CB%7d&Source=");
        return false;
      });
    }
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('changeLink');

Comment: This worked: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeLink() {
      $("#idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ6").removeAttr('onclick');
      $("#idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ6").attr("href", "#");
      $("#idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ6").click(function () {
        NewItem2(event, "https://........ /_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=%YourListIdhere%&Source="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href));
        return false;
      });

    }

    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('changeLink'); 

</script>

Comment: So I got the script to work but SharePoint still adds the model dialog at the end IsDlg=1, so last step is I just need to remove or override that.  The script does not specify it but SharePoint adds it.  Will let you know when I figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to share two approaches that worked for me, depending on whether you want full page non-modal or modal dialog:

1. As Full Page Non-Modal

$(function () {
$("#idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ6").attr("href", "https://SiteName/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={2D0B41F6-84B5-469D-86DC-446215EA47CB}&Source="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href));
$("#idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ6").attr("onclick", "");
});

2. As Modal Dialog

function changeLink() {
$("#idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ6").removeAttr('onclick');
$("#idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ6").attr("href", "#");
$("#idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ6").click(function () {
NewItem2(event, "https://SiteName/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={2D0B41F6-84B5-469D-86DC-446215EA47CB}&Source="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+" ");
return false;
});
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('changeLink');

Hope this might be helpful to someone else.